# why does my counter increase according to the lens of char input in C++

Tags: c++

I'm picking up on C++ recently and is trying to code a program which prompts for names for a defined no. of times and inserts each of the input into an array of size-5. The problem happened when I tried to run the following code, my counter, i increases according to the no of len the user input. Why is that so?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    const int SIZE = 5;
    char name[SIZE];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if (strlen(name) <= 50) {
            cout << "Enter a name: \n";
            cin >> name[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        cout << name[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I got your question right but how about trying to store string instead of char in array?

Comment: `cin >> name[i];` reads a single character, was this intended?

Comment: @Malin isn't storing string must be in a char array too?

Comment: Also `strlen(name)` calls undefined behavior since `name` isn't initialized.

Comment: @EtAndrea yes but it would be string[] or char**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (strlen(name) <= 50) {
```

You should not call `strlen` on array which is not initialized.

Use array of `strings` otherwise

```
    cout << name[i] << endl;
```

refers to `i`-th character, not entire string. Or if you want to go with `char` arrays, you'd need a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

I thing what you indended to do was :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

const int SIZE = 5;
string names[SIZE];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        cout << "Enter a name: \n";
        string name;
        cin>>name;
    if (strlen(name) <= 50) {
        cin >> names[i];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    cout << name[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

UNTESTED

Answer (score 0):

The second for loop, which does the output, does this in single characters, incrementing **i** each time.

To output the string all at once assign a string pointer to **name[0]** and send that to **cout**.